# Code Obfuscator for any Java Project

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, netbeans, obfuscation

I am searching for Java code obfuscator like  the one in Netbeans J2ME Project and in Android Project in Eclipse- to works with **any (not only J2ME)** Java project in Eclipse and Netbeans.

Is there any plugin or external application , that I am looking for?

Comment: [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) is a widely used one. Generally the same obfuscators used in J2ME should be usable for Java SE applications as well.

Comment: In Netbeans IDE, there is no obsfucation options for J2SE Project Properties. How can we apply obsfucation for J2SE project in Netbeans?

Comment: For ProGuard in NB integration look at the PG manual - Ant task chapter. You will include PG into your build.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) is the established standard, I guess

Comment: hi, how do we use it with Java SE application?

Answer (score 4):

If you are also want "string encryption" the Stringer Java Obfuscator has Eclipse Plugin but it is commercial obfuscator: [Marketplace Link](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/stringer-java-obfuscation-toolkit)

N.B. I'm CEO at Licel LLC. Developer of Stringer Java Obfuscator.